# Hide view controller when button pressed / Keep custom configuration of viewcontroller - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

this is a basic issue that I can't seem to find a way to solve. Basically, i am when a button is pressed, it shows me a certain view, and when another button on that view is pressed, it takes me back to view one. HOWEVER, problem is, that whatever custom configuration I do on second view (like setting a UIImageView with a pickerview, or entering text), it resets to original view as soon as I go back to first and come back to second view. I tried linking a button from view one to two then from view two to one, but it erases. I also tried to dismiss the view, but that erases custom configuration too.

```
- (IBAction)hidePrize:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And as seen in this image,
http://oi57.tinypic.com/mutrvd.jpg
in the second view, creating custom settings are erased once you go back to first and then back to second.

Therefore, my concern is, how can i make it so that any custom configuration made is kept even when leaving that view and coming back. Is there someway I can hide the view controller? I am only a beginner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are talking about transition between two viewControllers not just views. Am I right?

If you put two views on a big scrollView and scroll from one to another. Then the settings wouldn't disappear when you scroll back. But the sample picture you linked shows you didn't do it this way.

viewController wouldn't preserve the data itself. So you must do it yourself. Every time when viewController `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` cache the data with any data preservation method you like such as `NSKeyedArchiver`. And every time when viewController `viewWillAppear` read the cache data first. If it's not nil configure UI with it.